# Wait for program to load before continuing

Tags: vb.net

Morning everyone!
I use the below code to launch a call center program...programatically.  I'm using a delay (versus a threading.sleep) and it works fine, but what i would rather do is a (wait until program loads, then execute the rest of my function).

```
If cbNJ.Checked Then
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\Scripts\Agent Group Occupancy - SD_NJ.acsup")
            delay(8000)
            AppActivate("Avaya CMS Supervisor")
```

I'd rather have:

```
If cbNJ.Checked Then
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\Scripts\Agent Group Occupancy - SD_NJ.acsup")
            'delay(8000)
            Wait for prior instruction to complete then continue to next line...
            AppActivate("Avaya CMS Supervisor")
```

How can i invoke wait for instruction to complete before continuing?

Comment: If the other project doesn't tell you it's running that is a not so easy to answer I believe. You can do stuff like search for a Window with the respective title and define this as "Program is running", but that does not mean the program is actually ready to process further input or something like that.

Comment: Is this call center program yours so you can modify the code?